# SUM total hours

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate the total hours of my `horas` column with this code:

```
string query = "SELECT n_projeto, SUM(horas) FROM projetos";
```

And it gives this error:

> No column named 'hours' was found.

But I have that column created with the exact same name, what am I missing here?

Comment: Uh, you're not selecting `hours` in your query.

Comment: There's a typo somewhere. In the query its spelled `horas` but the message says `hours`. More than likely, the actual query being executed is spelled `hours`.

Comment: Can that query execute without a `group by` clause?

Comment: I translated the error message, i'm portuguese so the column is actually named "horas"

Comment: Assuming the error is raised by the application and not SQL Server... you need to name the column using `AS something`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You have to give a name to your aggregate field.

2) Your query will not work after you'll correct it. I assume you will get an error

> Column 'projetos.n_projeto' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

You need to group the data by a field you want to select like this:

```
string query = "SELECT n_projeto, SUM(horas) as horas FROM projetos GROUP BY n_projeto";
```

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing that you intend:

```
string query = "SELECT SUM(horas) as hours FROM projetos";
```

If you want this per project:

```
string query = "SELECT n_projeto, SUM(horas) as hours FROM projetos GROUP BY n_projeto";
```

Comment: I´m creating a graph that makes the relation between n_projeto and horas column

Comment: You should add the group by clause